# Issue With Spring: There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, endpoint

I am going through this book on restful web services with spring. I decided to move away from what they were doing and use java configuration files. For some reason, after switching over to the Java configuration, the service would run (in the console window) correctly but when I actually go to the endpoint on localhost i get this:

> White label Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> Sat Apr 23 20:48:25 PDT 2016 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

And this is the response from the GET request:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1461470029110,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/greeting"
}
```

The next chapter of this story begins with me going to the getting started page on the Spring website http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ I decided to start a small project recreating their basic tutorial. I will post the code I wrote below for you to see. The problem is, I am having the exact same issue. The service runs but I can't hit the endpoints. I am not sure what is going on and I have seen others with similar issues, but the answers have not applied/helped with mine. I am sure it is something obvious that I am doing wrong and any help would be greatly appreciated. One last piece of information, if at all relevant, I am using IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE as my IDE.

The endpoint being hit:

http://localhost:8080/greeting

My controller

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {
    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World")String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

My Resource Representation class

```
public class Greeting {
    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

My Main

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

My POM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.organization_name.webservices</groupId>
<artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Command line to run

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

My complete log from the console

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.3.RELEASE)

2016-04-23 20:47:53.153  INFO 7898 --- [           main] c.t.webservices.application.Application  : Starting Application on Macintosh.local with PID 7898 (/Users/<my_user>/Downloads/B04788_Code/HelloWorld/target/classes started by <my_user> in /Users/<my_user>/Downloads/B04788_Code/HelloWorld)
2016-04-23 20:47:53.156  INFO 7898 --- [           main] c.t.webservices.application.Application  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-04-23 20:47:53.242  INFO 7898 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@68ceda24: startup date [Sat Apr 23 20:47:53 PDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-04-23 20:47:54.084  INFO 7898 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2016-04-23 20:47:54.811  INFO 7898 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-04-23 20:47:54.840  INFO 7898 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-04-23 20:47:54.841  INFO 7898 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
2016-04-23 20:47:54.960  INFO 7898 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-04-23 20:47:54.960  INFO 7898 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1736 ms
2016-04-23 20:47:55.214  INFO 7898 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-04-23 20:47:55.218  INFO 7898 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-04-23 20:47:55.219  INFO 7898 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-04-23 20:47:55.219  INFO 7898 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-04-23 20:47:55.219  INFO 7898 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-04-23 20:47:55.545  INFO 7898 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@68ceda24: startup date [Sat Apr 23 20:47:53 PDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-04-23 20:47:55.605  INFO 7898 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-04-23 20:47:55.606  INFO 7898 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-04-23 20:47:55.628  INFO 7898 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-04-23 20:47:55.628  INFO 7898 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-04-23 20:47:55.657  INFO 7898 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-04-23 20:47:55.776  INFO 7898 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-04-23 20:47:55.848  INFO 7898 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-04-23 20:47:55.853  INFO 7898 --- [           main] c.t.webservices.application.Application  : Started Application in 3.531 seconds (JVM running for 4.702)
2016-04-23 20:48:19.521  INFO 7898 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-04-23 20:48:19.521  INFO 7898 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-04-23 20:48:19.533  INFO 7898 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 12 ms
```

Console update after GET request

```
2016-04-23 20:48:19.521  INFO 7898 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-04-23 20:48:19.533  INFO 7898 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 12 ms
```

Console after stopping

```
2016-04-23 20:53:24.494  INFO 7898 --- [       Thread-2] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@68ceda24: startup date [Sat Apr 23 20:47:53 PDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-04-23 20:53:24.495  INFO 7898 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown

Process finished with exit code 130
```

Thanks again for any help you can offer. I will keep everyone posted with updates!

Comment: Just to be clear - you are seeing the whitelabel error page when you go to http://localhost:8080/greeting or just http://localhost:8080? I see the same when I go to http://localhost:8080, but it works just fine when I go to /greeting.

Comment: good question, I should have been more clear. Yes, the GET is made towards the endpoint itself, localhost:8080/greeting

I updated the question to reflect that now :)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I believe your issue is related to packages. Your application is defined in `com.organization_name.webservices.application`. I am guessing your other classes are in a different package that is not a child of `com.organization_name.webservices.application`. Spring will automatically load controllers that are in the same package or sub-packages, for example:

```
com.organization_name.webservices.application
com.organization_name.webservices.application.controllers
```

But not packages like this:

```
com.organization_name.webservices.controllers
```

You can fix this by either moving your controller (or application), or adding `ComponentScan` to your Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses=GreetingController.class)
public class Application {
```

You should be seeing this in your log:

```
 Mapped "{[/greeting]}" onto public com.organization_name.webservices.xxx.Greeting com.organization_name.webservices.xxx.GreetingController.greeting(java.lang.String)
```

Comment: Had to additionally add:     `import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;`   
          `import main.java.hello.GreetingController;`

Comment: Sometimes this error will also appear if your request mapping is not handled by any controller.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful!

Answer (score 11):

seems like you are missing thymleaf dependency. Put this inside your pom.xml dependencies

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Exactlly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in pom.xml add the following dependency

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep your controller inside the main class package:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    Adding these dependencies helped me :

<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
public class swagger {
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.Mongo"))
                .paths(regex("/mongo.*"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue but when i added to my pom.xml this dependency and it works well for me

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```