# Autowired not working, error 'required a bean of type...'

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven

I'm trying to run a Spring Boot application. 
In the first place, I did not indicate the package in Application java with scanBasePackages. So my application run but I have an issue like that : [Issue With Spring: There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819277/issue-with-spring-there-was-an-unexpected-error-type-not-found-status-404)
When I add scanBasePackages at Application class, I get :

> Field userService in fr.umlv.orthopro.controller.UserController
>   required a bean of type 'fr.umlv.orthopro.service.UserService' that
>   could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'fr.umlv.orthopro.service.UserService' in your configuration.

So I found answers, it seems to be package's arrangement. But like I say before I add scanBasePackages annotations without succes and even when I try to restructuring my packages manually it didn't works.
So after many hours on that, I can't figure it out where the problem come from.

My packages structure:

```
src/
├── main/
│   └── java/
|       ├── fr.umlv.orthopro.app/
|       |   └── Application.java
|       ├── fr.umlv.orthopro.controller/
|       |   ├── UserController.java
|       |   ├── SentenceController.java
|       |   └── RuleController.java
|       ├── fr.umlv.orthopro.service/
|       |  ├── UserService.java
|       |  ├── UserServiceIT.java
|       |  ├── SentenceService.java
|       |  ├── SentenceServiceIT.java
|       |  ├── RuleService.java
|       |  └── RuleServiceIT.java
|       └── fr.umlv.orthopro.db/
|           ├── UserService.java
|           ├── UserServiceIT.java
|           └── SentenceService.java
```

This is my Application.java file (without imports)

```
import fr.umlv.orthopro.controller.UserController;

    @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"fr.umlv.orthopro.app", "fr.umlv.orthopro.controller",
            "fr.umlv.orthopro.db", "fr.umlv.orthopro.service"})
    @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses=UserController.class)
    public class OrthoproApp {
        public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
            SpringApplication.run(OrthoproApp.class, args);
        }

        @Bean
        public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
            return args -> {

                System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

                String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
                Arrays.sort(beanNames);
                for (String beanName : beanNames) {
                    System.out.println(beanName);
                }

            };
        }
    }
```

- Controller class (the other are empty for the moment)

```java
    @RestController
    @Component
    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public class UserController {

        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;
        ...
}
```

- Service class (the other are similar)

```java
package fr.umlv.orthopro.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import fr.umlv.orthopro.db.User;

@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public abstract class UserService implements UserServiceIT{

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceIT userRepo;

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        List<User> users = userRepo.findAll();
        return users;
    }

    @Override
    public User findById(int id) {
        User user = userRepo.findOne(id);
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public User create(String username, String password, String email, String first_name, String last_name, boolean admin) 
                    throws NullPointerException, IllegalArgumentException {
        User new_user = new User();

        List<User> userLst = findAll();
        for(User tmp_u:userLst) {

                if(tmp_u.getUsername().equals(username))
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Username alredy exist");
        }
        new_user.setUsername(username);
        new_user.setEmail(email);
        new_user.setPassword(password);
        new_user.setAdmin(admin);
        new_user.setFirstName(first_name);
        new_user.setLastName(last_name);

        new_user = userRepo.save(new_user);

        if(new_user == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("Save user has failed");

        return new_user;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public User update(int id, String username, String password, String email, String first_name, String last_name, Boolean admin)
                    throws NullPointerException {
        User userToUpdate = findOne(id);

        if (userToUpdate == null) 
                throw new NullPointerException("Update user by id " + id + " has failed");

        if (username != null)
            userToUpdate.setUsername(username);
        if (email != null)
            userToUpdate.setEmail(email);
        if (password != null)
            userToUpdate.setPassword(password);
        if (admin != null)
            userToUpdate.setAdmin(admin);
        if (first_name != null)
            userToUpdate.setFirstName(first_name);
        if (last_name != null)
            userToUpdate.setLastName(last_name);


         User updatedUser = userRepo.save(userToUpdate);
         if (updatedUser == null) 
                throw new NullPointerException("Save updated user by id " + id + " has failed");

          return updatedUser;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public void delete(int id) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        try {
            userRepo.delete(id);
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Save updated user by id " + id + " has failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

- My Interface of a Service

```java
package fr.umlv.orthopro.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import fr.umlv.orthopro.db.User;

public interface UserServiceIT extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{

    List<User> findAll();

    User findById(int id);

    User create(String username, String password, String email, String first_name, String last_name, boolean admin) 
            throws NullPointerException, IllegalArgumentException;

    User update(int id, String username, String password, String email, String first_name, String last_name, Boolean admin)
            throws NullPointerException ;

    void delete(int id) throws IllegalArgumentException;

}
```

My Logs

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for fr.umlv.orthopro:OrthoPro_brain:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 5.2.12.Final @ line 138, column 19
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building OrthoPro_brain 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ OrthoPro_brain >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ OrthoPro_brain ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ OrthoPro_brain ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ OrthoPro_brain ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/Unconnu/Desktop/orthopro/OrthoPro_brain/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ OrthoPro_brain ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ OrthoPro_brain <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ OrthoPro_brain ---

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.9.RELEASE)

2017-12-30 19:51:29.818  INFO 13291 --- [           main] fr.umlv.orthopro.OrthoproApp             : Starting OrthoproApp on MacBook-Pro-de-Unconnu.local with PID 13291 (/Users/Unconnu/Desktop/orthopro/OrthoPro_brain/target/classes started by Unconnu in /Users/Unconnu/Desktop/orthopro/OrthoPro_brain)
2017-12-30 19:51:29.821  INFO 13291 --- [           main] fr.umlv.orthopro.OrthoproApp             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-12-30 19:51:29.944  INFO 13291 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@17fd8a8c: startup date [Sat Dec 30 19:51:29 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-30 19:51:35.325  INFO 13291 --- [           main] org.xnio                                 : XNIO version 3.3.8.Final
2017-12-30 19:51:35.359  INFO 13291 --- [           main] org.xnio.nio                             : XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.8.Final
2017-12-30 19:51:35.448  WARN 13291 --- [           main] io.undertow.websockets.jsr               : UT026009: XNIO worker was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default worker will be used
2017-12-30 19:51:35.449  WARN 13291 --- [           main] io.undertow.websockets.jsr               : UT026010: Buffer pool was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default pool will be used
2017-12-30 19:51:35.532  INFO 13291 --- [           main] io.undertow.servlet                      : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-12-30 19:51:35.533  INFO 13291 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5596 ms
2017-12-30 19:51:35.813  INFO 13291 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-12-30 19:51:35.883  INFO 13291 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-30 19:51:35.884  INFO 13291 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-30 19:51:35.884  INFO 13291 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-30 19:51:35.885  INFO 13291 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-30 19:51:37.559  INFO 13291 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-12-30 19:51:37.649  INFO 13291 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-12-30 19:51:37.989  INFO 13291 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.12.Final}
2017-12-30 19:51:37.991  INFO 13291 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-12-30 19:51:38.127  INFO 13291 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-12-30 19:51:38.513  INFO 13291 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2017-12-30 19:51:38.691  INFO 13291 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
2017-12-30 19:51:41.379  INFO 13291 --- [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@23fb847f'
2017-12-30 19:51:41.410  INFO 13291 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-12-30 19:51:41.508  WARN 13291 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'fr.umlv.orthopro.service.UserServiceIT' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2017-12-30 19:51:41.508  INFO 13291 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-12-30 19:51:41.509  INFO 13291 --- [           main] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed drop of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2017-12-30 19:51:41.572  INFO 13291 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-12-30 19:51:42.193 ERROR 13291 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userService in fr.umlv.orthopro.controller.UserController required a bean of type 'fr.umlv.orthopro.service.UserServiceIT' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'fr.umlv.orthopro.service.UserServiceIT' in your configuration.

[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:527)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'fr.umlv.orthopro.service.UserServiceIT' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at fr.umlv.orthopro.OrthoproApp.main(OrthoproApp.java:15)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'fr.umlv.orthopro.service.UserServiceIT' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 25 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 24.029 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-30T19:51:42+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 34M/112M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project OrthoPro_brain: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'fr.umlv.orthopro.service.UserServiceIT' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)} -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: You neglected to show the code for the `UserService`, which is what it's looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my post, please let me know if you need more details

Comment: It is possible that sometimes the class is already imported thru' another Jar which interferes with the existing class or interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. @RestController is a combination of @controller+@ResponseBoby. If you mention @RestController, you don't need to mention @component and @ResponseBody for each method.
2. When you mention @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages=, it will scan the packages mentioned, no need to mention  @ComponentScan separately.
   3.I can see 2 UserService.java in package structure, check whether you imported correctly.

Thanks,
Divya

Answer (score 0):

Remove `implements UserServiceIt` in `UserService` class as the `@Service` is not a repository. I would suggest also changing name of `UserServiceIT` to `UserRepository` and adding `@Repository` annotation.

Comment: Do the class UserService need to extends JpaRepository directly to use `save` `delete` etc ?

Comment: you don't want to use this methods directly in the service class. Instead use the autowired `userRepo` field

Comment: please check out the [example](https://javabeat.net/spring-data-jpa/). It shows proper approach (Repository -> Service -> Controller>). Hope I was helpful

Comment: I change `UserServiceIT` to `UserRepository` and add `@Repository`, I remove the implements from UserService and change `private UserServiceIt userRepo` to `private UserRepository userRepo` but I have the same problem

Comment: did you do:
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("fr.umlv.orthopro") ?

Comment: Yes, and still nothing unfortunatly, I read your example, and I still don't understand what is wrong in my project..

Comment: Probably the reason is the bean creation process fails on you service class. Can you show complete application log? (from startup to error)

Comment: I edit my first post with my logs, please let me know if you need more details

Comment: `Field userService in fr.umlv.orthopro.controller.UserController required a bean of type 'fr.umlv.orthopro.service.UserServiceIT' that could not be found.`. You did something wrong in the controller. Assuming you refactored `UserServiceIT` to `UserRepository` the class `UserServiceIT` should not be seen in your project anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this annotation:

```
@SpringBootApplication(com.package.pathTotheBean/*)
```