# Soap spring boot wsdl generated app fails with 404 no message available

Tags: maven, web-services, tomcat, spring-boot, http-status-code-404

What I am using:
netbeans 8.2
spring boot
Maven 4.0
tomcat 8.5

Here is the POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-sem-ds</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demoSemDs</name>

    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlFiles>
                                <wsdlFile>tissSolicitacaoProcedimentoV3_03_02.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            </wsdlFiles>
                            <vmArgs>
                                <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
                            </vmArgs>
                            <staleFile>${project.build.directory}/jaxws/stale/tissSolicitacaoProcedimentoV3_03_02.stale</staleFile>
                        </configuration>
                        <id>wsimport-generate-tissSolicitacaoProcedimentoV3_03_02</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <!--<execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlFiles>
                                <wsdlFile>tissSolicitacaoProcedimentoV3_03_02.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            </wsdlFiles>
                            <vmArgs>
                                <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
                            </vmArgs>
                            <staleFile>${project.build.directory}/jaxws/stale/tissSolicitacaoProcedimentoV3_03_02_1.stale</staleFile>
                        </configuration>
                        <id>wsimport-generate-tissSolicitacaoProcedimentoV3_03_02_1</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    </execution>-->
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
                        <artifactId>webservices-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxws-wsimport</sourceDestDir>
                    <xnocompile>true</xnocompile>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                    <catalog>${basedir}/src/jax-ws-catalog.xml</catalog>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--<version>2.0.2</version>-->
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>jax-ws-catalog.xml</include>
                                <include>wsdl/**</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here are my generated classes for the webservice:
Application:

```
package com.example.demosemds;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoSemDsApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                SpringApplication.run(DemoSemDsApplication.class, args);
        }
}
```

Servlet:

```
package com.example.demosemds;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
                return application.sources(DemoSemDsApplication.class);
        }

}
```

WebService Operation:

```
package com.example.demosemds;

import br.gov.ans.padroes.tiss.schemas.StTissFault;
import br.gov.ans.padroes.tiss.schemas.TissFaultWS;
import br.gov.ans.tiss.ws.tipos.tisssolicitacaoprocedimento.v30302.TissFault;
import javax.jws.WebService;

/**
 *
 * @author chris
 */
@WebService(serviceName = "tissSolicitacaoProcedimento", portName = "tissSolicitacaoProcedimento_Port", endpointInterface = "br.gov.ans.tiss.ws.tipos.tisssolicitacaoprocedimento.v30302.TissSolicitacaoProcedimentoPortType", targetNamespace = "http://www.ans.gov.br/tiss/ws/tipos/tisssolicitacaoprocedimento/v30302", wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/tissSolicitacaoProcedimentoV3_03_02.wsdl")
public class DemoSemDsWSFromWSDL {

    public br.gov.ans.padroes.tiss.schemas.AutorizacaoProcedimentoWS tissSolicitacaoProcedimentoOperation(br.gov.ans.padroes.tiss.schemas.SolicitacaoProcedimentoWS solicitacaoProcedimento) throws TissFault {
        //TODO implement this method
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented yet.");

        TissFaultWS tissFaultWS = new TissFaultWS();
        tissFaultWS.setTissFault(StTissFault.HASH_INVALIDO);
        throw new TissFault("Something at last!", tissFaultWS);
    }

}
```

When I run this it deploys to the tomcat server on port 8090. But when I call it on `localhost:8090/demo-sem-ds` I just get the Whitelabel Error Page: `There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). No message available`.

I don't know if it's related, but I also get an INFO message in the tomcat log when running the application saying: `org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath`.

I have searched the internet, mainly StackOverflow, to try and find a definitive answer, but so far I haven't had any luck.

I would be most grateful if anyone can help me. Please let me know if there is anything extra I can add to the question.

Thanks,

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819277/issue-with-spring-there-was-an-unexpected-error-type-not-found-status-404) but as you can see, my spring-boot classes are all in the same package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 1:**

Sorry about replying like this. I ran out of characters in the question.

I saw in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819277/issue-with-spring-there-was-an-unexpected-error-type-not-found-status-404) that @markwatsonatx suggested that `Mapped "{[/demo-sem-ds]}"` should be somewhere in the log. However, I can't find it in my tomcat output.

Here's the tomcat output just when running the project:

```
10-Jan-2018 17:02:30.431 INFORMAÇÕES [http-nio-8090-exec-35] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\conf\Catalina\localhost\demo-sem-ds.xml]
10-Jan-2018 17:02:44.330 INFORMAÇÕES [http-nio-8090-exec-35] com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.<init> WSSERVLET14: Inicializando servlet de JAX-WS
17:02:45.307 [http-nio-8090-exec-35] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'servletConfigInitParams' with lowest search precedence
17:02:45.323 [http-nio-8090-exec-35] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'servletContextInitParams' with lowest search precedence
17:02:45.347 [http-nio-8090-exec-35] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'jndiProperties' with lowest search precedence
17:02:45.347 [http-nio-8090-exec-35] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'systemProperties' with lowest search precedence
17:02:45.347 [http-nio-8090-exec-35] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'systemEnvironment' with lowest search precedence
17:02:45.347 [http-nio-8090-exec-35] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [StubPropertySource@927279822 {name='servletConfigInitParams', properties=java.lang.Object@69dde978}, StubPropertySource@166873606 {name='servletContextInitParams', properties=java.lang.Object@1b7de455}, JndiPropertySource@99663534 {name='jndiProperties', properties=org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate@3e00141}, MapPropertySource@408537409 {name='systemProperties', properties={java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, catalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5, sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers, catalina.useNaming=true, os.name=Windows 10, sun.boot.class.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\classes, java.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\conf\logging.properties, sun.desktop=windows, java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.runtime.version=1.8.0_131-b11, user.name=chris, tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToScan=log4j-web*.jar,log4j-taglib*.jar,log4javascript*.jar,slf4j-taglib*.jar, shared.loader=, tomcat.util.buf.StringCache.byte.enabled=true, user.language=pt, java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory, sun.boot.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin, PID=14652, jdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048, java.version=1.8.0_131, java.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager, user.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo, sun.arch.data.model=64, java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.threadFactory=org.apache.catalina.startup.SafeForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory, java.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\endorsed, sun.cpu.isalist=amd64, sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252, file.encoding.pkg=sun.io, package.access=sun.,org.apache.catalina.,org.apache.coyote.,org.apache.jasper.,org.apache.tomcat., file.separator=\, java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification, java.class.version=52.0, user.country=BR, java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre, java.vm.info=mixed mode, os.version=10.0, path.separator=;, java.vm.version=25.131-b11, org.jboss.logging.provider=slf4j, user.variant=, java.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources, java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob, sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle, awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit, package.definition=sun.,java.,org.apache.catalina.,org.apache.coyote.,org.apache.jasper.,org.apache.naming.,org.apache.tomcat., user.script=, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.apache.naming, user.home=C:\Users\chris, java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip=bootstrap.jar,commons-daemon.jar,tomcat-juli.jar,annotations-api.jar,el-api.jar,jsp-api.jar,servlet-api.jar,websocket-api.jar,jaspic-api.jar,catalina.jar,catalina-ant.jar,catalina-ha.jar,catalina-storeconfig.jar,catalina-tribes.jar,jasper.jar,jasper-el.jar,ecj-*.jar,tomcat-api.jar,tomcat-util.jar,tomcat-util-scan.jar,tomcat-coyote.jar,tomcat-dbcp.jar,tomcat-jni.jar,tomcat-websocket.jar,tomcat-i18n-en.jar,tomcat-i18n-es.jar,tomcat-i18n-fr.jar,tomcat-i18n-ja.jar,tomcat-juli-adapters.jar,catalina-jmx-remote.jar,catalina-ws.jar,tomcat-jdbc.jar,tools.jar,commons-beanutils*.jar,commons-codec*.jar,commons-collections*.jar,commons-dbcp*.jar,commons-digester*.jar,commons-fileupload*.jar,commons-httpclient*.jar,commons-io*.jar,commons-lang*.jar,commons-logging*.jar,commons-math*.jar,commons-pool*.jar,jstl.jar,taglibs-standard-spec-*.jar,geronimo-spec-jaxrpc*.jar,wsdl4j*.jar,ant.jar,ant-junit*.jar,aspectj*.jar,jmx.jar,h2*.jar,hibernate*.jar,httpclient*.jar,jmx-tools.jar,jta*.jar,log4j*.jar,mail*.jar,slf4j*.jar,xercesImpl.jar,xmlParserAPIs.jar,xml-apis.jar,junit.jar,junit-*.jar,hamcrest-*.jar,easymock-*.jar,cglib-*.jar,objenesis-*.jar,ant-launcher.jar,cobertura-*.jar,asm-*.jar,dom4j-*.jar,icu4j-*.jar,jaxen-*.jar,jdom-*.jar,jetty-*.jar,oro-*.jar,servlet-api-*.jar,tagsoup-*.jar,xmlParserAPIs-*.jar,xom-*.jar, java.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Oracle\ora12c_65bits\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin;C:\Oracle\ora12c_32bits\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin;C:\Oracle\ora11g_720\product\11.1.0\client_1;C:\Oracle\ora11g_720\product\11.1.0\client_1\bin;C:\Oracle\ora11g_621\product\11.1.0\client_1;C:\Oracle\ora11g_621\product\11.1.0\client_1\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\maven\bin;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\maven\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\SimplePass\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;., java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/, spring.beaninfo.ignore=true, java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation, common.loader="${catalina.base}/lib","${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar","${catalina.home}/lib","${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar", java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, sun.java.command=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start, java.class.path=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\bin\tomcat-juli.jar, java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification, java.vm.specification.version=1.8, catalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5, sun.cpu.endian=little, sun.os.patch.level=, java.awt.headless=true, java.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\temp, java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/, server.loader=, os.arch=amd64, java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment, java.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext, user.dir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\bin, line.separator=
, java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, file.encoding=Cp1252, java.specification.version=1.8}}, SystemEnvironmentPropertySource@1819461971 {name='systemEnvironment', properties={NB_EXEC_TOMCAT_START_PROCESS_UUID=tomcat80:home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5, USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=PC-CONSULTORIO, PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6, Platform=HPD, FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO, _RUNJAVA="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe", JSSE_OPTS="-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048", SESSIONNAME=Console, ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData, JAVA_OPTS= "-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048" -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources, PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64, TNS_ADMIN=C:\Chris\Work\TNS, PSModulePath=C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ResourceManager\AzureResourceManager\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\Storage\, SystemDrive=C:, JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131, USERNAME=chris, ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86), FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING=Default, PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC, ProgramData=C:\ProgramData, ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files, HOMEPATH=\Users\chris, _RUNJDB="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\jdb.exe", PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel, LOGGING_CONFIG=-Djava.util.logging.config.file="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\conf\logging.properties", ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files, PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public, CURRENT_DIR=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\bin, windir=C:\WINDOWS, =::=::\, NB_TOMCAT_JDK=1.8, LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local, MSMPI_BIN=C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\, CATALINA_TMPDIR=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\temp, USERDOMAIN=PC-CONSULTORIO, FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING=Internet Explorer, LOGONSERVER=\\PC-CONSULTORIO, JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131, PROMPT=$P$G, FSHARPINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.1\Framework\v4.0\, asl.log=Destination=file, CATALINA_BASE=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5, OneDrive=C:\Users\chris\OneDrive, =C:=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\bin, APPDATA=C:\Users\chris\AppData\Roaming, GTK_BASEPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\, _EXECJAVA="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe", VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\, CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files, Path=C:\Oracle\ora12c_65bits\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin;C:\Oracle\ora12c_32bits\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin;C:\Oracle\ora11g_720\product\11.1.0\client_1;C:\Oracle\ora11g_720\product\11.1.0\client_1\bin;C:\Oracle\ora11g_621\product\11.1.0\client_1;C:\Oracle\ora11g_621\product\11.1.0\client_1\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\maven\bin;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\maven\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\SimplePass\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;, OS=Windows_NT, COMPUTERNAME=PC-CONSULTORIO, CATALINA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5, MAINCLASS=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap, LOGGING_MANAGER=-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager, OnlineServices=Online Services, PROCESSOR_REVISION=3c03, CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\bin\tomcat-juli.jar, CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files, ComSpec=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe, SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS, TEMP=C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp, ACTION=start, HOMEDRIVE=C:, USERPROFILE=C:\Users\chris, TMP=C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp, CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files, NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=4}}]
17:02:45.491 [http-nio-8090-exec-35] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Replacing PropertySource 'servletContextInitParams' with 'servletContextInitParams'

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.9.RELEASE)

2018-01-10 17:02:47.145  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] c.example.demosemds.ServletInitializer   : Starting ServletInitializer on PC-Consultorio with PID 14652 (C:\Users\chris\Documents\NetBeansProjects\demoSemDsProject\target\demo-sem-ds-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes started by chris in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\bin)
2018-01-10 17:02:47.148  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] c.example.demosemds.ServletInitializer   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-01-10 17:02:47.378  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@186f3e22: startup date [Wed Jan 10 17:02:47 BRST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-01-10 17:02:52.088  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bdca92aa] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-01-10 17:02:52.224  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2018-01-10 17:02:52.274  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4896 ms
2018-01-10 17:02:54.021  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-01-10 17:02:54.022  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'messageDispatcherServlet' to [/services/*]
2018-01-10 17:02:54.022  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-10 17:02:54.022  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'metricsFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-10 17:02:54.022  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-10 17:02:54.022  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-10 17:02:54.022  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-10 17:02:54.023  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-10 17:02:54.023  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-10 17:02:54.023  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-10 17:02:55.527  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@186f3e22: startup date [Wed Jan 10 17:02:47 BRST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-01-10 17:02:55.975  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-01-10 17:02:55.979  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-01-10 17:02:56.076  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-10 17:02:56.076  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-10 17:02:56.257  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-10 17:02:57.428  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/auditevents || /auditevents.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.AuditEventsMvcEndpoint.findByPrincipalAndAfterAndType(java.lang.String,java.util.Date,java.lang.String)
2018-01-10 17:02:57.433  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/loggers/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint.get(java.lang.String)
2018-01-10 17:02:57.433  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/loggers/{name:.*}],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint.set(java.lang.String,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-01-10 17:02:57.433  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/loggers || /loggers.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-01-10 17:02:57.433  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/trace || /trace.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-01-10 17:02:57.434  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2018-01-10 17:02:57.434  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics || /metrics.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-01-10 17:02:57.434  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mappings || /mappings.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-01-10 17:02:57.435  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/autoconfig || /autoconfig.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-01-10 17:02:57.436  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2018-01-10 17:02:57.436  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env || /env.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-01-10 17:02:57.437  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/info || /info.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-01-10 17:02:57.501  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/heapdump || /heapdump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/octet-stream]}" onto public void org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HeapdumpMvcEndpoint.invoke(boolean,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException,javax.servlet.ServletException
2018-01-10 17:02:57.503  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/health || /health.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.security.Principal)
2018-01-10 17:02:57.506  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/beans || /beans.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-01-10 17:02:57.509  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/configprops || /configprops.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-01-10 17:02:57.513  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/dump || /dump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-01-10 17:02:58.035  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-01-10 17:02:58.080  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2018-01-10 17:02:58.292  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] c.example.demosemds.ServletInitializer   : Started ServletInitializer in 12.74 seconds (JVM running for 2359.263)
10-Jan-2018 17:02:58.328 INFORMAÇÕES [http-nio-8090-exec-35] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\conf\Catalina\localhost\demo-sem-ds.xml] has finished in [27,898] ms
2018-01-10 17:02:58.304  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] com.sun.xml.ws.server.http               : WSSERVLET12: inicializaÃ§Ã£o do listener de contexto de JAX-WS
2018-01-10 17:02:58.305  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-35] com.sun.xml.ws.server.http               : WSSERVLET12: inicializaÃ§Ã£o do listener de contexto de JAX-WS
10-Jan-2018 17:02:58.367 INFORMAÇÕES [http-nio-8090-exec-35] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/demo-sem-ds]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
2018-01-10 17:02:59.296  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-38] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-01-10 17:02:59.427  INFO 14652 --- [io-8090-exec-38] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 131 ms
```

...and the application startup output:

```
Deploying on Apache Tomcat or TomEE
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
In-place deployment at C:\Users\chris\Documents\NetBeansProjects\demoSemDsProject\target\demo-sem-ds-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fchris%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext8200228991787487399.xml&path=/demo-sem-ds
OK - Deployed application at context path [/demo-sem-ds]
start?path=/demo-sem-ds
OK - Started application at context path [/demo-sem-ds]
```

Thanks again.



**Update 2:**

A colleague showed me how to get the proper response.

When I run the ws project, it was opening `http://localhost:8090/demo-sem-ds/`, but the url needs to have the name of the webservice on the end. In this case `http://localhost:8090/demo-sem-ds/tissSolicitacaoProcedimento`. Using this in SoupUI, with an appropriate call message, allows the webservice to reply.